# Многоуровневые таблицы страниц в виртуальной памяти

Tags: виртуальная-память

В чём заключается суть использования многоуровневых таблиц страниц виртуальной памяти? Цель - сократить расходы физической памяти на хранение сведений о страницах, т.к., например, на 4 Гб физической памяти при размере страницы в 4 Кб потребуется около 1 млн. записей в PTE. Читал где-то что для решения так же этой проблемы таблицы страниц хранятся не в реальной, а в виртуальной памяти и сами становятся объектами страничной организации. Связаны ли эти две идеи вместе?

Не понятно как от разбивания записей о страницах по каталогам у нас получиться какая то экономия... Если я файлы по куче подпапок раскидаю, результирующий размер только увеличиться, т.к. придётся ещё и хранить сведения о каталогах. Другое дело если бы какие то каталоги выгружались на диск и сведениях об этом каталоге указывалось, что он выгружен на диск. Но это вроде как не так происходит.

Answer (score 1):

Суть идеи в том, что при многоуровневой трансляции нам не нужен **непрерывный** кусок памяти.

Кстати, все "горячие" трансляции хранятся в так называемой [TLB](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) (translation lookaside buffer) (обычно это небольшая полностью ассоциативная память). Поэтому большинство трансляций происходит за 1 такт процессора вообще без доступа к таблицам трансляции адресов в памяти.

Comment: А по какому принципу записи PTE добавляются в TLB?

Comment: _"Суть идеи в том, что при многоуровневой трансляции нам не нужен непрерывный кусок памяти."_ - Поясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Выгружаются ли наименее используемые таблицы страниц на диск ради экономии места?

Comment: `А по какому принципу записи PTE добавляются в TLB?` -- если запись есть в таблице трансляции, то этим занимается аппаратура MMU (обычно варианты LRU (замещаем наиболее старую)), если нет -- ОС получает `page fault`, корректирует таблицу трансляции и инвалидирует в TLB одну (или несколько, зависит от алгоритмов) записей в TLB

Comment: `Выгружаются ли наименее используемые таблицы страниц на диск ради экономии места?` -- не знаю (очевидно, что зависит от ОС). (Если отправляем весь процесс в swap, то я бы вытеснял). Можете посмотреть сами код Linux в github

Comment: `Поясните пожалуйста` -- виртуальный адрес делится на диапазоны. Каждый из них это индекс в таблице трансляции соответствующего уровня. Соответствующая запись в таблице это либо (управляется флагами) адрес таблицы следующего уровня, либо физический адрес сегмента памяти, содержащего транслируемый адрес (это конец в цепочке трансляций). Понятно, что таблицы более нижнего уровня (размер каждой это одна физическая страница) могут размещаться вразброс

Comment: Я просил пояснить в чём заключается выигрыш от того, что таблицы нижнего уровня расположены в разброс? Если в этом есть смысл, зачем тогда делать более 2 таблиц?

Comment: _Выгружаются ли наименее используемые таблицы страниц на диск ради экономии места?_ - Ну такие решения имеют распространение? А как это вообще делается? Нужно как-то запомнить, что страница выгружена на диск.

Comment: _Если отправляем весь процесс в swap, то я бы вытеснял_ - Кстати, хотел узнать. А что, есть какое то специальное разделение виртуальных страниц по процессам? Что такая то страница принадлежит конкретному процессу или группа страниц принадлежит одному процессу?

Comment: _обычно варианты LRU (замещаем наиболее старую)_ - Значит нужно как то понять какая самая старая. Как MMU это понимает?

Comment: `Что такая то страница принадлежит конкретному процессу или группа страниц принадлежит одному процессу?`  -- да, у каждого процесса свой набор таблиц трансляции. В MMU есть регистр (вообще говоря несколько регистров, по одному для каждого уровня исполнения (в разных архитектурах у этого понятия разные наименования)), который адресует таблицу трансляции верхнего уровня. / **У меня встречный вопрос -- вы сколько страниц чего-нибудь уже прочли на эту и близкие к ней темы?**

Comment: `Как MMU это понимает?` -- хороший вопрос. Обычно производитель скрывает ответ. Возможные варианты рассмотрены, например, [тут](https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall13/CSCI-GA.2250-001/lectures/Lecture-06.pdf)

Comment: _У меня встречный вопрос -- вы сколько страниц чего-нибудь уже прочли на эту и близкие к ней темы?_ - Не так уж и много. Исчерпывающих и понятных источников найти не выходит. Нужно одновременно не слишком подробно и не слишком поверхностно. Весь материал в сети который я читал, как видите, довольно поверхностный.

Comment: Я тут поискал в сети по TLB LRU чего-то не слишком длинного и не поверхностного. Даже серьезного не слишком много. Вот, набрел на пару ссылок -- [Least recently used (lru) cache replacement implementation using a fifo](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20150026410) и [Translation Caching: Skip, Don’t Walk (the Page Table)](https://www.cs.rice.edu/CS/Architecture/docs/barr-isca10.pdf) / Ну, вы уж сами поразбирайтесь, может нам краткое и не поверхностное изложение напишите -)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82687/discussion-between-avp-and-d-stark).